# Use Add in AddAssign

Tags: rust, struct, operation

I have two structs say `struct A` and `struct B`. I have the `Add` implemented for `A` and `B`.

```
impl Add<&B> for A{
    type Output = A;
    fn add(self, rhs: &B) -> A{
    --snip--
}
```

Now, I want to implement the `AddAssign`, but I think there should be an idiomatic way to use `Add`. Something like:

```
impl AddAssign<&B> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &B) {
        *self = *self + rhs;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to chain them together, but you're running to the issue of a dereference causing a move out of a borrowed value. It's typically easier to go the other way around, and implement `AddAssign`, then use that in `Add`. You can change the `self` to be `mut self`, which takes ownership as usual, but just allows it to be modified in place, then immediately returned:

```rust
struct A;
struct B;

impl Add<&B> for A {
    type Output = A;

    fn add(mut self, rhs: &B) -> A {
        self += rhs;
        self
    }
}

impl AddAssign<&B> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &B) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

If you really need them to be in that order, `A` has to be `Copy` and/or `Clone`. That could look like:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct A;
struct B;

impl Add<&B> for A {
    type Output = A;

    fn add(mut self, rhs: &B) -> A {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl AddAssign<&B> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &B) {
        *self = *self + rhs
    }
}
```

or

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct A;
struct B;

impl Add<&B> for A {
    type Output = A;

    fn add(mut self, rhs: &B) -> A {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl AddAssign<&B> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: &B) {
        *self = self.clone() + rhs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question is how to use Add in AddAssign, not the inverse. So, I would like to know what to put instead of *self=*self+rhs;

Comment: @Jaafar sure, I added an example to do it that way using derivable traits. `Copy` isn't often implementable because that requires your struct to only consist of nearly only primitives, but you can derive `Clone` for almost everything.